# How to set unique values within an array to '0' instead of undefined? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, undefined

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and have only been in the game for a few days. I got bored of watching tuts and decided to make a small game.

So, the program is a lemonade stand. I created an inventory function that stores the what type/number of materials bought within the shop function, though when I display the inventory all variables that do not have a set number read as 'undefined'. For consistency I'd like them to read '0'.

Code:

```
function playerInv(){
    const inv = [oldAmountprompt, lemAmountprompt, freshAmountprompt, sugarAmountprompt, tapAmountprompt, distAmountprompt, iceAmountprompt];
    let userprompt = prompt('Inventory:\n' + inv[0] + ' x Old Lemons\n' + inv[1] + ' x Regular Lemons\n' + inv[2] + ' x Fresh Lemons\n' + inv[3] + ' x Sugar\n'
    + inv[4] + ' x Tap Water\n' + inv[5] + ' x Distilled Water\n' + inv[6] + ' x Bags of Ice');

        if(inv[0] == 'undefined' && inv[1] == 'undefined' && inv[2] == 'undefined' && inv[3] == 'undefined' && inv[4] == 'undefined' && inv[5] == 'undefined'
        && inv[6] == 'undefined' && inv[7] == 'undefined')
        {

        }
}
```

After executing, the console reads:

```
5         x Old Lemons
undefined x Regular Lemons
undefined x Fresh Lemons
etc, etc.
```

Comment: There's no problem with the array. Your `lemAmountprompt`, `freshAmountprompt`, etc variables are undefined. Initialize them to 0 before using them and you won't have to use workarounds like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use map to map all undefined to 0.

```
inv = inv.map(item => item === undefined ? 0 : item);
```

Also check out the fill method. `inv.fill(0);`